# Exception on apache kafka - Error getting request for apikey: 3 and apiVersion: 2

Tags: apache-kafka

I am considerably new to Apache Kafka and Spring Kafka and am writing an application which consumes information from a topic and performs some operation.

I wrote a simple consumer using @KafkaListener annotation and testing it against my local Kafka Server 0.10.1.1 and it worked all fine.

Now when i am pointing to our DEV server of Kafka (version - 0.10.0.2.5) i see i get the below exception on the client side logs:

```
network.Selector - Connection with qm-alpha.activehealth.net/10.42.53.152 disconnected
java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:83) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.1.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom(NetworkReceive.java:71) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.1.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive(KafkaChannel.java:154) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.1.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read(KafkaChannel.java:135) ~[kafka-clients-0.10.1.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:343) [kafka-clients-0.10.1.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:291) [kafka-clients-0.10.1.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:260) [kafka-clients-0.10.1.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:232) [kafka-clients-0.10.1.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:180) [kafka-clients-0.10.1.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:193) [kafka-clients-0.10.1.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:248) [kafka-clients-0.10.1.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1013) [kafka-clients-0.10.1.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:979) [kafka-clients-0.10.1.1.jar!/:?]
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:532) [spring-kafka-1.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_121]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_121]
```

Also, i see the below errors on the server side logs:

```
kafka.network.InvalidRequestException: Error getting request for apiKey: 3 and apiVersion: 2
        at kafka.network.RequestChannel$Request.liftedTree2$1(RequestChannel.scala:95)
        at kafka.network.RequestChannel$Request.<init>(RequestChannel.scala:87)
        at kafka.network.Processor$$anonfun$processCompletedReceives$1.apply(SocketServer.scala:488)
        at kafka.network.Processor$$anonfun$processCompletedReceives$1.apply(SocketServer.scala:483)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at kafka.network.Processor.processCompletedReceives(SocketServer.scala:483)
        at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:413)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid version for API key 3: 2
        at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.ProtoUtils.schemaFor(ProtoUtils.java:31)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.ProtoUtils.requestSchema(ProtoUtils.java:44)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.ProtoUtils.parseRequest(ProtoUtils.java:60)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.MetadataRequest.parse(MetadataRequest.java:96)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.AbstractRequest.getRequest(AbstractRequest.java:48)
        at kafka.network.RequestChannel$Request.liftedTree2$1(RequestChannel.scala:92)
```

I searched a few and found this is basically because of versioning problem between the client and the server, but could not find a way to resolve this.

Comment: It looks like kafka clients with version 0.10.0.x are not really compatible with 0.10.1.x brokers and found Spring kafka version 1.1.2.RELEASE uses kafka client 0.10.1.1
Here is where i found the information: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/confluent-platform/TyOMM8hDXOw

Comment: Ok - I got it to work by overriding the dependencies, actually re-declaring the dependency with kafka-clients version 0.10.0.1. However i would like to know if this is the right approach or if there is a better approach to do this?

Comment: That is the right approach. Kafka clients are pretty tightly tied to brokers. We will release a 1.2 release soon for the 0.10.2.x client. The 2.0 snapshot already supports that., with 2.0 M1 due soon.

Comment: FYI: Since Kafka 0.10.2 the Kafka clients are not tightly tied to brokers any more.  Moving forward, Kafka clients are/will be backwards-compatible as well as forward-compatible with Kafka brokers. Example: You can use 0.10.2 clients with 0.10.1 brokers (this is new!), and once 0.10.3 or 0.11.0 is released, 0.10.2 will also work with those newer brokers. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-97%3A+Improved+Kafka+Client+RPC+Compatibility+Policy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work by overriding the dependency kafka-clients as below in the pom.xml.

```
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.0.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

This error can also occur if there is a broker version mismatch. I recently ran into this error (in a 3 node cluster) where 1 broker was started on version 1.0.0 and the other 2 were started on 0.10.x. Aligning all the brokers to version 1.0.0 fixed the issue.